# Can I use 802.11ac instead of 802.11g for Personal Hotspot when both of my devices support it?

Tags: iphone, wifi, macbook-pro, tethering

I have an iPhone 6 and the 2013 rMBP. Both support 802.11ac WiFi, yet the iPhone always sets up the hotspot as 802.11g for backwards compatibility (I think). Is there a way to change this? My unlimited LTE is capable of reaching 60Mbps and WiFi is becoming the bottleneck.

I was hoping perhaps Yosemite's instant hotspot would be able to tell the iPhone what kind of a network to set up?

Comment: Sidenote : use USB tethering to avoid that bottleneck until you find a better solution.

Comment: My Mac is currently connected to my iPhone using personal hotspot using 802.11n (2.4 GHz) PHY mode. (of course, it's been almost 3 years since this question was posted so maybe they've updated something in between)